# iOS 7 and UITableViewDelegate with shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I use method `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);`

This method in iOS 6 called when user tap in cell

Apple write about it:

> // -tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath: is called when a touch
>   comes down on a row.  // Returning NO to that message halts the
>   selection process and does not cause the currently selected row to
>   lose its selected look while the touch is down.

But in iOS 7 this method call even when I try scroll my `UITableView`. Why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When the user holds their finger on the cell before scrolling, the cell is highlighted.

Instead, you might want to use this:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```